# Автоматическая card flip анимация кнопки + генерация случайного числа на ней

Tags: java, android, анимация, случайные-числа

В android и java новичок, пилю первое приложение)

Используя гайд (http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html#views), создал кнопку, которая вращается при нажатии, отображая один из двух вариантов текста на ней. Требуется заставить эту кнопку вращаться автоматически через требуемые промежутки времени, чтобы, при этом, при каждом повороте кнопки, на ней (в свойстве text) отображалось новое сгенерированное генератором случайных чисел число.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое можно осуществить?

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+timer    2. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+generate+random+number

Answer (score 1):

Таймер можно реализовать так:

```
new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {       
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          
           System.out.println("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);      
       }

       public void onFinish() {         
           //Action!!! 
       }   
}.start();
```